# Is there a way to automatically update the readme in installaware 9?

Tags: installation, installaware

The title basically says it all. I have a readme dialog during the setup and I need the setup to get a readme.txt file from a designated folder and update it whenever the setup is run. For example the app.config file updates whenever the setup is built. Is there a way to do the same with the readme?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the file readme.rtf in the project directory it will be used instead of the one specified in the GUI. The new file will be used after the project is built. The readme is compiled into the setup as a support file so the readme has to be changed before the build.